# Java application on Microsoft Surface not full screen

Tags: java

I have a Java application, developed in eclipse and with an exe wrapper. It runs full screen on a win 7 desktop, but not on a Win 8 surface (original) with Intel HD Graphics 4000. When run on the surface it has black space all around it. I found multiple references to updating the graphics driver to get extra options about how the screen scales. The latest drivers from Intel are rejected when I try to install them. If I try to do an update via device manager it says I am current. Looking for any suggestions/info. Thank you.

--- add ons ---

### Surface has Java 8 update 65

```
public class Fullscreen
{
private static GraphicsDevice _device   = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
private static DisplayMode      _oldMode    = null;

public static   Drawable        _drawable;
public static   BufferStrategy  _bufStrat;
public static   int             _frameCount;
public static   long            _secondTrack;

//==========================================================================
/**
 * Set some video related stuff
 * @param frame         - The App's JFrame
 * @return                  - true if sucessful
 */

public static boolean set( JFrame frame )
{
    frame.setResizable              ( false );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    if (MainBase._fullScreen) // Is true for this version
    {
        frame.setUndecorated        ( true );
        frame.setIgnoreRepaint  ( true );

        if (MainBase._fullScreen && !_device.isFullScreenSupported())
        {
            System.err.println( "Full screen not supported" );
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            _device.setFullScreenWindow( frame );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            _device.setFullScreenWindow( null );
            System.err.println( "Failed setting full screen" );
            return false;
        }

        _oldMode = _device.getDisplayMode();
        //TODO: what to do about display refresh vs frame rate
        DisplayMode displayMode = new DisplayMode( MainBase._screenW, MainBase._screenH, 32, 60); //MainBase._fps );
        if (displayMode != null && _device.isDisplayChangeSupported())
        {
            try
            {
                _device.setDisplayMode( displayMode );
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _device.setDisplayMode( _oldMode );
                _device.setFullScreenWindow( null );
                System.err.println( "Failed setting full screen mode" );
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //System.out.println( "Display Mode W " + MainBase._screenW + " H " + MainBase._screenH + " BitDepth " + 32 );

    return true;
}
```

----- Important info although not solved -----

I tried to update the surface to Win 10. The update failed. I then rolled back to Win 8. After I reinstalled my extra stuff the application ran at full screen. Until it crashed and I had to kill it in Task Manager. After that it was back to not full screen. Something obviously got tweaked or carried of from that run. Not a solution but an important lead to follow.

Comment: Considering that Java is kinda dependent on the system having the newest Java Libraries, I would guess that either Java is out of date, or they simply haven't updated the support for that device.

Comment: How about some code, showing what you've tried? No need for your whole application, but how about showing up how you are setting up the parent window for the application?

Comment: Can you at least provide the code which makes the application full-screen?  Are you using [setFullScreenWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow-java.awt.Window-), maximizing your window, or just setting its bounds directly?

Comment: Added more info above including the Full screen part of the code.

Comment: Could be high-dpi mode.  Right click on the desktop and select "Display Settings".  Then make sure the slider for "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" is on the far left at 100%.  Log out and log back into your computer after that change.  Any luck?

Comment: Setting the one scaling level for all my displays option and choosing Smaller - 100% as selbie suggested made the problem less bad. (But still not full screen)